Accordion expands all accordions on click
I'm trying to create my own accordion component using Vue3 composition. I have a problem when I click one accordion it will open, expand, and show that accordions content, but it will also expand all other accordions on the page as well. The other accordions don't get their content displayed which makes sense since each accordion has an v-if=isOpen but I don't understand why the heights for all other accordions is being modified.
I'm not sure if its the CSS being applied which expands them or if something related to vue is doing this

<template>
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-header" @click="toggle">
      <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
      <span :class="['chevron', { rotated: isOpen }]">
        <img :src="chevronIcon" />
      </span>
    </div>
    <div v-if="isOpen" class="accordion-body">
      <p>{{ content }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps } from 'vue'
import chevronIcon from '/images/chevron.svg'

interface Props {
  title: string
  content: string
  isOpen: boolean
  accordionId: string | null
}

const props = defineProps<Props>()

const emit = defineEmits<{
  accordionClick: [accordionId: string]
}>()

const toggle = () => {
  emit('accordionClick', props.accordionId!)
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.accordion {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
}

.accordion-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: none;
  }
}

.chevron {
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  height: 30px;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion-body {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition:
    max-height 0.3s ease,
    opacity 0.3s ease;
  max-height: 500px;
}
</style>


Post your accordion component.

Could be the parent being a flex container and its children taking full height.

Can you create a minimal reproducible example on codepen or code sandbox?

Just use v-model for isOpen, that will make isOpen individual for each accordion:
Playground
const isOpen = defineModel<boolean>('isOpen');


Great solution. Since you only need one model in the Accordian component you could also using the default model by
<Accordian v-model="isOpen[idx]" />```

Thank you for the solution. It turns out the issue is as Amaury had suggested, which is a flex parent container and its children taking the full height. Although i have implemented this solution to make the accordion much simpler
